# Resolve java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "" without losing placeholder text

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext

Initializing the `EditTexts` on `onCreate` is returning a "" which cannot be cast into valid double hence this error. Using an explicit value might help but then I will lose the `android:hint` text. 
How can I resolve this issue without losing the `android:hint` text ?

`Code`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private double quant, problem, verbal;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    EditText quantScore = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.quant);
    EditText problemScore = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.problem);
    EditText verbalScore = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.verbal);
    Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);



    quant = Double.valueOf(quantScore.getText().toString());
    problem = Double.valueOf(problemScore.getText().toString());
    verbal = Double.valueOf(verbalScore.getText().toString());

    final double total = quant + problem + verbal;




    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The total is " +total, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });




}
```

`Layout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Score To Percentile"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/quant"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:hint="Quantitative Ability"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/problem"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/quant"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="Problem Solving"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColorLink="#ffffdbeb"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/verbal"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:hint="Verbal Ability"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColorLink="#ff48f3ff"
    android:layout_below="@+id/problem"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Calculate"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/verbal"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:typeface="monospace" />
```

Comment: Exactly what you want to do??? Hint is meant for input value for EditText.

Comment: @Clairvoyant - If I use `android:text = "0"`, my issue may get resolved but the Hint would not show up then.

Comment: offcourse hint will not show if you input any value to EditText. Hint is meant for that thing only so user get an indea which type of value user have to put in EditText

Comment: Yeah! I wanted a resolution for that.

Comment: You have accepted an answer already which i can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should catch the NumberFormatException and provide the desired default value.

```
try {
   quant = Double.valueOf(quantScore.getText().toString());
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
   quant = 0;
}
```

This will work for any text that can't be parsed to **Double** not only when the `EditText` is empty.

Comment: But throwing an exception and catching it is quite expensive, it would be effective to set a default value and do a null check.

Comment: and when he enters `blabla` in the text what would you do? I think the regex will be more expensive

Comment: Agree to it when user enters characters, but not sure if regex has an upper hand or handling exception.

Comment: No more exception but when I try to `TOAST` the value of `verbal` entering `10`, I get a 0.0

Comment: @ɥʇᴉɾuɐɹ I'm not sure either. It will not matter from the side of the performance, these are not the things that makes the app slow.

Comment: @Maven You should put the code that get the value on your `OnClickListener` jst before the `Toast`.

Comment: Oh yeah! I just missed that.